# Bxslider not working in Firefox and IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

So the slider should be displaying 5 slides and responding down to 1 based on viewport size. In Chrome/Opera, this seems to be working, but in Firefox and IE11, it only shows 1 slide. Any ideas?

My slider is live here: http://www.peaceloveanddecorating.com/store/pg/537-Lenny-Eva-Style-Guide.html

Here is the code:

```html
<div>
    <ul class="bxslider" style="text-align: center; ">
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-wide-cuffs-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 1</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/large-sentiments-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 2</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-thin-cuff-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 3</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-pendants-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 4</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-beaded-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 5</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-wraps-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 6</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-flourish-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 7</span></li>
      <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-mini-charms-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 8</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
</script>
<script>
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      maxSlides: 5,
      slideWidth: 200,
      slideMargin: 10
    });
</script>
```

This is in the head:

```html
<script src="/Shared/Themes/Base/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Shared/Themes/Base/CSS/jquery.bxslider.css">
```

Comment: Use snippets for displaying snippets that can get executed. Not for showing code, please.

Comment: That's a request, I know you didn't know before. `:)`

Comment: Why are you initializing two instances of Bxslider? Only one suffice

Comment: That was the problem! Stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IndieRok pointed out in the comments, I was initializing bxSlider twice, which was causing the problems. Changing the code to the example below fixed it.

```
<div>
<ul class="bxslider" style="text-align: center; ">
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-wide-cuffs-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 1</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/large-sentiments-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 2</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-thin-cuff-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 3</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-pendants-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 4</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-beaded-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 5</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-wraps-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 6</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-flourish-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 7</span></li>
  <li><img src="/images/brands/lenny-eva/lenny-eva-mini-charms-cat.jpg"><span class="le-slider-text">Test 8</span></li>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
     maxSlides: 5,
     slideWidth: 200,
     slideMargin: 10
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes that I was thinking too that instead of initializing twice here need to initialize once.